# How to use 'mailto' attribute without opening a browser tab using JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json, leaflet

**Issue Faced**

JSON popup opens a new browser tab, as well as a default email program, when clicking on a `mailto` link in the map popup.

**What I Am Doing**

Using Leaflet for showing map markers, I am using a JSON file to display the markers which produce a popup.

This part works just fine. The problem is when I click on the `mailto` email address, it also opens a new browser tab.

I have tried to replace the attribute `url` with various other attributes, like `href` or `link`, but these just render the link as unusable.

This is the code I am using in the JSON file.

```
markers = [
  {
    "name": "NameNo1",
    "url": "mailto:mail@name1.com",
    "lat": 3.046111,
    "lng": 101.606111
  },
  {
    "name": "NameNo2",
    "url": "mailto:mail@name2.com",
    "lat": 2.9580555,
    "lng": 101.78666
  },
  {
    "name": "NameNo3",
    "url": "mailto:mail@name3.com",
    "lat": 3.008611,
    "lng": 101.592222
  }
];
```

**What I Want To Happen**

When clicking on the `mailto` link in the popup, only the default email program should open.

How can this JSON code be adjusted, so that when I click on the `url` field, it only opens the default email program, and does not open a new browser tab?

Comment: "This is the code I am using in the JSON file" — That is JavaScript, not JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer was in my code in the javascript file, i was using:

```
 L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], {icon: myIcon} )
.bindPopup( '<a href="' + markers[i].url + '" target="_blank">' + markers[i].name + '</a>' 
)
.addTo( map );
```

I have changed the target to top:

```
 L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], {icon: myIcon} )
.bindPopup( '<a href="' + markers[i].url + '" target="_top">' + markers[i].name + '</a>' )
 .addTo( map );
```

I cannot believe it was so simple, I just spent hours trying to fix this in json